# Converting rows from one pandas dataframe column to multiple columns without numeric data?

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I am working with data in a tabular format where I would like each row to be one individual. Currently duplicates at the individual level occur because there are duplicates in another column for each individual.

Example Input Table:

```
+-------------+--------+
| EMPLOYEE_ID | COLORS |
+-------------+--------+
|      111111 | BLUE   |
|      222222 | GREEN  |
|      333333 | RED    |
|      333333 | GREEN  |
+-------------+--------+
```

Example Desired Output Table:

```
+-------------+---------+---------+
| EMPLOYEE_ID | COLOR_1 | COLOR_2 |
+-------------+---------+---------+
|      111111 | BLUE    |         |
|      222222 | GREEN   |         |
|      333333 | RED     | GREEN   |
+-------------+---------+---------+
```

The number of duplicates is variable (i.e. there could be a COLOR_3, COLOR_4, etc.).

Please let me know; I have tried using pivot_table but seem to be running into the issue of the data I am trying to pivot (COLORS in the original table) being categorical rather than numerical.

Thanks!

Comment: check with cumcount and pivot

Comment: @WeNYoBen: IIRC, you answered this type of question several times in the past. So, this time you don't want to flag this duplicate anymore :p

Comment: @AndyL. feel bored .ha